# Spring data elasticsearch 3.1 configuration

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use spring data with elastic search version 6. Since this version only has the REST client, the only version of spring-data-elasticsearch that supports it is **3.1.0.RC2**. Spring posted documentation for this version but there is no information on how to configure it to connect to elastic search's REST client. Does anyone know how to find this information?

What's also interesting is the documentation gives an example of how to create an embedded instance but all of the classes/annotations it says to use are all missing from the *spring-data-elasticsearch.3.1.0.RC2.jar*. E.g. `@EnableElasticsearchRepositories`, `ElasticsearchOperations`, and `ElasticsearchTemplate`

**Edit:** The missing classes were actually due to eclipse not automatically pulling in the manually downloaded jars even though I had gradle pointing to them. But the question still remains.

---

**Update:**
I looked into georges van's suggestion. I created a bean for `RestHighLevelClient` but I don't see a way to use it to configure the `ElasticsearchTemplate`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(/*expects org.elasticsearch.client.Client*/);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    // org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient does not extend org.elasticsearch.client.Client
    public RestHighLevelClient getRestClient() {
        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("theserver", 9200)));
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Do I even need the `ElasticsearchOperations` bean? It's in the documentation so I can't tell.

Also, when I run only the getRestClient() bean I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getRestClient' defined in class path resource [com/example/ElasticsearchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory method 'getRestClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory method 'getRestClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:729)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:95)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1184)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:732)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:925)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:870)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:343)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:853)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.decodeCacheFiles(PluginRegistry.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.loadFromMainClassLoader(PluginRegistry.java:119)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createPatternParser(PatternLayout.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:128)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:56)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder.build(PatternLayout.java:377)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:70)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:145)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:74)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:195)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:492)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(ESLoggerFactory.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(ESLoggerFactory.java:53)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:38)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.ParseField.<clinit>(ParseField.java:35)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$getDefaultNamedXContents$47(RestHighLevelClient.java:673)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient$$Lambda$57.00000000119BE790.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:204)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1707)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:523)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:719)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:245)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:510)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.getDefaultNamedXContents(RestHighLevelClient.java:674)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(RestHighLevelClient.java:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(RestHighLevelClient.java:200)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(RestHighLevelClient.java:192)
    at com.example.ElasticsearchConfig.getRestClient(ElasticsearchConfig.java:23)
    at com.example.ElasticsearchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29592f91.CGLIB$getRestClient$0(<generated>)
    at com.example.ElasticsearchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29592f91$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b12c3bab.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.example.ElasticsearchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29592f91.getRestClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

---

**Update:** *spring-data-elasticsearch.3.1.0.RELEASE* is now out but there is still no documentation on how to configure it as a REST client.

Comment: try this https://github.com/hakdogan/ElasticSearch

Answer (score 0):

To configure the ElasticsearchTemplate, you can inject the Client into the bean

```
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, ...);
    }
```

Comment: Trying that I get `No qualifying bean of type 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client' available`